# Access Memorystore (Redis) using VPC Peering

Tags: google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-memorystore

Imagine I have a VPC called `vpc-1` which has a Memorystore (Redis) instance associated with it.  My understanding is that Redis lives in its own VPC and there is VPC peering used to connect `vpc-1` to the VPC for Redis.  Now let us imagine I create a second VPC called `vpc-2` and peer that VPC with `vpc-1`.  I now create a VM with a network interface to `vpc-2`.  This VM can now access VPC resources attached to `vpc-1` and `vpc-2`.  However, because VPC peering is not transitive, the VM can't access the Redis instance.

My puzzle now becomes one of ... is it possible for a VM attached to `vpc-2` that is VPC peered to `vpc-1` which has a Memorystore (Redis) instances associated with it (`vpc-1`) to access that Redis instance?

I realize that I can switch my story to use Shared VPC ... however I'm wondering what options exist if I want to use VPC Peering exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussions with technical folks who know GCP VPC and GCP Memorystore very well, it seems that there is no way to have transitive peering using VPC Peering.  A solution was suggested that, for my use case, worked well.  With respect to the original story, we created a new Compute Engine in the `vpc-1` VPC which has access to Redis.  On that Compute Engine we installed the open source package called [nutcracker](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) which provides a Redis proxy.  What this means is that a Redis client request sent to this Compute Engine is proxied to the real Redis server managed by Google through Memorystore.  Since the Compute Engine is an *ordinary* compute resource in the `vpc-1` VPC its internal IP address is reachable from other VPCs peered with `vpc-1` (for example, in our story `vpc-2`).  The end result was that a Compute Engine created in `vpc-2` could then target the Compute Engine running `nutcracker` using the Redis protocols.  That Compute Engine then relayed the request to the real Redis server and all worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with a similar setup. After some researches I found severals recommendations like Kolban's about using twemproxy (nutcracker). Also you can find this scenario in Google's documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/running-redis-on-gcp-four-deployment-scenarios

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).